# Nunit Negative Tests Expected Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit, .net-4.5

I have a class that I check the index or the length of the string. And I want to write a Nunit Negative Test:

- if the length of the string Out of Range the Nunit Test is true. Or the first index is digit "false" the Nunit Test is true.

What i try:

**My CheckKeyClass:**

```
public void SetKey(string keyToAnalyse) 
{
  Line = new string[keyToAnalyse.Length];
  int nummeric;
  bool num;  

  if (Line.Length == 0 || Line.Length < 24) 
  {
    throw new Exception("Index Out of Range " + Line.Length);
  }
  // Ist Product a Character
  num = int.TryParse(Line[0], out nummeric);
  if (!num) 
  {
    if (Line[0] == "K") 
    {
      Product = 0;
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    throw new Exception("The Productnumber is not right: " + Line[0] ". \nPlease give a Character.");
  }
}
```

**My Nunit Test:**

```
[Test]
public void NegativeTests() 
{
  keymanager.SetKey("KM6163-33583-01125-68785");
  // Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => keymanager.Line[24]);
}

// ExpectedException Handling
public static void Throws<T>(Action func) where T : Exception 
{
  var exceptionThrown = false;
  try 
  {
    func.Invoke();
  } 
  catch (T) 
  {
    exceptionThrown = true;
  }

  if (!exceptionThrown) 
  {
    throw new AssertFailedException(String.Format("An exception of type {0} was expected, but not thrown", typeof(T)));
  }
}
```

So if the Line.length Out of Range the Test must be green also true.
How do I use that the Tests is true?

thx

Comment: can you not use the built-in [`Assert.Throws<T>`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assertThrows&r=2.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Assert.Throws()`

```
string keyHasLengthOf24 = "KM6163-33583-01125-68785";

var ex = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => keymanager.SetKey(keyHasLengthOf24));

Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("Index Out of Range "));
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609536/nunit-assert-throws) for further detail.