# How to write a test that ensures if all methods throw an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have several methods that expect an instance of an interface `ITable`. Now I´m not sure if it is worth the effort of creating a test for this parameter for every method, this seems like a break on DRY.

So I wonder if there is a possibilty to call all those methods within one single test-method and assert that all of them fail for the same reason - in my case an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: The Visual-Studio NUnit-extension

Comment: XUnit or NUnit have test parameters for this purpose, I'm sure there are other testing frameworks that do too.

Comment: @HimBromBeere here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609536/nunit-assert-throws

Comment: @SergeyKolodiy There is no `Assert.Throws` within VS integrated NUnit-framework

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's strange, we are using NUnit and I see lots of `Assert.Throws<T>(...)` in our tests. Make sure you are not confusing NUnit with MSTest, which has an attribute for that.

Comment: [Yes there is](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5)

Comment: @JonHanna To avoid further confudion: I´m using this VS-extension for the tests https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099. And there is no `Assert.Throws` but an attribute called `ExpectedException`. However the question is on setting ALL calls to expect that specific exception.

Comment: Does that extension work if you pull in a current version of NUnit through Nuget? It'd be easier to use `Assert.Throws` for this, and then you'd have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution, it´s not nice but it does its work. For that I simply loop all the methods within the type to test and check if there is any parameter within the methods list that implements the interface:

```
var funcs = typeof(MyType).GetMethods().Where(x => x.GetParameters().Any(y => typeof(ITable).IsAssignableFrom(y.ParameterType)));
```

Now I can loop this collection and call its methods via reflection. Finally I just count how often an eception of type `ArgumentException` has been thrown by incrementing a counter when the exception is hit:

```
foreach (var func in funcs)
{
    try {func.Invoke(myInstance, myArgs);}
    catch(ArgumentException) { i++; }
}
```

If the counter is equal to the number of methods found the test is successfull:

```
Assert.AreEqual(i, expectedCount);
```

Comment: Writing the code in this manner will make it extremely difficult to track and analyse failures; I'd strongly recommend looking into `AutoFixture.Idioms` as alluded to in Mark's answer assuming you have any interesting quantity of these kinds of requirements as it really is made for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoFixture.Idioms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Idioms) for that, although by default it'll test for `ArgumentNullException` because `null` is really the only *invalid* value for an interface.

You can write something like this to check all members for invalid values (including members that take `ITable` as an argument):

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var assertion = new GuardClauseAssertion(fixture);
assertion.Verify(typeof(MyType));
```

The `Verify` call will throw an exception if it passing `null` as an argument doesn't throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

There are lots of options for narrowing down the selection. As an example, there's a `Verify` overload that takes `IEnumerable<MemberInfo>`, so you can use Reflection to query your type for all members that have an `ITable` argument.

If you need specific help with AutoFixture or AutoFixture.Idioms, please ask a new question and tag it *autofixture*, as it can become a bit tiresome answering complex questions in the comments :)